# How to access a PostgreSQL Database with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I access a PostgreSQL Database with javascript?

I saw that node.js is a possibility or a REST-like Service, or sth else. what do you recommend?

Comment: "with JavaScript" running where? In the browser? On a server? From command line on your machine? Inside a desktop app?

Comment: See for example https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres

Comment: Javascript should run on the server. (We develop a Webapp in the Ratchet Framework for Android and iOS if that helps)